# Expo Cannot Find Module after reinstall

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, expo

I'm having issues getting expo to start.  It tries to open dev tools and dev tools will not open and gives me this error:

```
Cannot find module 'C:\Users\charl\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo- 
cli\node_modules\@expo\image-utils\build\index.js'. Please verify that the 
package.json has a valid "main" entry
Error: Cannot find module 
'C:\Users\charl\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo- 
cli\node_modules\@expo\image-utils\build\index.js'. Please verify that the 
package.json has a valid "main" entry
at tryPackage (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:227:19)
at Function.Module._findPath (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:364:18)
at Function.Module._resolveFilename 
(internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:597:27)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:526:27)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:666:19)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:16:16)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\@expo\xdl@55.0.4\src\AssetUtils.js:6:1)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:759:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:770:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:628:32)
```

This is for a react-native application, using NPM, Node, a Windows 10 machine.

I've tried reinstalling expo with npm and yarn, but i cant get it to work.  I looked and saw in the package.json file the 'main' key has a value of 'node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js'. Before this happened i was having trouble with expo that it told me that expo cant be recognized so i messed around with environment variables until it worked. Now this. Thank you guys for any help

Comment: Delete `node_modules` and `package-lock.json`, run `npm install` again.

Comment: I tried that, no luck. Uninstalling and reinstalling with npm and yarn doesn't work either

Comment: Is this the sequence of execution you've executed? `expo init youproject => cd youproject => expo start`

Answer (score 5):

Try running

```
npm install -g expo-cli --force
```

Answer (score 2):

Was having this same issue when using Windows **Powershell** or CMD.exe. Was able to get passed it by using Git Bash. Try running `npm install -g expo-cli` from a MINGW64 terminal (ex: Git Bash)

Answer (score 0):

1. "node_modules" folder copy/paste
   from C:\Users\charl.npm-global to C:\Users\charl\AppData\Roaming\npm\
2. npm i

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I sort out using two step

first download the Git Bash and installed it , once it was installed  open as administrator and wrote the code

`npm install -g expo-cli --force`